# help me understand the method Validator.TryValidateObject()

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

this is the method definition:

```
public static bool TryValidateObject(
Object instance,
ValidationContext validationContext,
ICollection<ValidationResult> validationResults,
bool validateAllProperties
```

)

what i am confused is the `validateAllProperties` parameter, I understand when it is true-validate all properties.

What about when it is false, not validate all properties, but which property will be validated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the property is false the Validator should validate each of the properties on the object that have a ValidationAttribute applied to them.  This can include any of these attributes: CustomValidationAttribute, DataTypeAttribute, RangeAttribute, RegularExpressionAttribute, RequiredAttribute, and StringLengthAttribute, along with any other attributes that derive from ValidationAttribute.

See the [MSDN library on the TryValidateObject method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411772(v=VS.95).aspx) for more information.

In the following example, Foo should be validated, while Bar should not.

```
public class Example
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Foo is a required property.")]
  public object Foo { get; set; }

  public object Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

See here for a good answer:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/605635/missleading-parametername-validateallproperties-in-validator-try-validate-componentemodel-dataannotations

It seems that when validateAllProperties is set to false that only the RequiredAttribute is validated.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't fully understand it but after struggling with Unit Testing custom validators written by me I noticed one interresting thing.

When I launched my tests without this parameter (so by default it was false), my custom validators were omitted! if I set it to true, they were taken into account in my tests and now I can happily continue TDD. Hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: this is also what i got, so i asked question about the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Arjen is right, only the Required attribute is validated when the validateAllProperties parameter is false.

I wrote a post about OData validation using DataAnnotations and I found the same issue.

http://blog.jorgef.net/2011/01/odata-dataannotations.html